# Capture a payment with Paypal API

Tags: php, paypal

I've created a **Payment** with the `Paypal API`, I have approved and execute the payment.

Now i would like to capture an amount. So i am making this **POST request**:

```
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/XXXXX/capture
```

It's working.

But the state is not **`captured`** it is **`partially_captured`**. I have to log in the `sandbox` and accept manually the payment.

Why do I have to do it manually ?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Does the amount you're trying to capture exactly match the originally authorised amount?

Comment: Nope, the original authorization is 10 USD and I want to capture only five (for my tests).

Answer (score 0):

The amount that you specify in the capture needs to match the originally authorised amount in order for the state to appear as `captured`.

This is specified in the API docs:

> *amount object* The amount to capture. If the amount matches the
>   orginally authorized amount, the state of the authorization changes to
>   **captured**. Otherwise, the state of the authorization changes to
>   **partially_captured**.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#capture

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if I want to capture a smaller amount do I need to accept it manually ? I can't find API methods to do that.

Comment: When you say accept it manually, do you mean accept it as the merchant or approve it as the customer?

Comment: I mean as the merchant. The client approves the payment. Later an administrator of my app will tell the API "Ok capture X USD" X in a smaller amount that the approved amount. When I'm doing that, the merchant need to accept it. I want it to be accepted automatically.

Comment: There are no solutions for that ?